# How to control a <label> with CSS?

Tags: css, label

I have this snippet:

```
      <label>&nbsp;</label><a id="whatever" 
      onclick="addmore('field_whatever', 'What's up?');">The deal is?</a><br/>
```

How do i use CSS to add space on the top or the bottom.  I am able to do it for margin-left but it won't work for margin-top nor margin-bottom.

Thanks

Comment: See my statement: "I am able to do it for margin-left but it won't work for margin-top nor margin-bottom."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`labels` are by default inline. They will not respond on top/bottom margin. You have to tell them to display as `block`/`inline-block` .

Like this

```
label { 
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px 0;
}
```

---

Additionally, your anchor has an un-escaped quote. Correct it as this

```
<a id="whatever" 
      onclick="addmore('field_whatever', 'What\'s up?');">The deal is?</a>
```

Comment: @AAA, Updated with some info as well.

Comment: Thanks.  is there a risk if there is an unescaped quote?

Comment: @AAA, Yeah the script will probably break.

Answer (score 1):

```
#whatever{
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    // etc, can even do this
    margin: 10px 10px 5px 20px;
}
```

Comment: also your onclick is broken.. you must remove the ' from what's

Comment: it seems to be working with the '.  however your method for css didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try display block, that should work.

```
label {
   display:block;
   margin:20px 0;
}
```

Comment: That worked but the "block" part is adding way too much space from the top even after i take off margin-top.  Do i do a negative margin-top?